# How to change below rewrite url to allow more sub folder, when all url redirected to index page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to change the below rewrite rule to accept more folders. Currently any other url else `mydomain.com\test`  will be directed to `index.php`.

```
RewriteRule ^((?!test).)*$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I need to add more subfolders like `test1`, `test2` etc. So that I can access url `\test1`, `\test2` etc.

**Rewrite Rule**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!test).)*$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...

What you have already also matches `/test1` and `/test2` because the regex you have only checks that something doesn't start with `/test`, and both `/test1` and `/test2` starts with `/test`.

But if you want it to check multiple folders that don't all start with the same thing, then use the `|` in the expression. Say you also want to exclude `/blah` and `/bleh`:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!test|blah|bleh).)*$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: @JustinJohn Works for me in my blank htaccess file. Try removing the negative look-ahead altogether then: `!^(test|blah|bleh)`

Answer (score 0):

one of many ways:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```