# URL Rewriting to subfolders based on the parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to Rewrite the URL to different sub folders based on the parameters passed in URL? i found the [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286584/how-to-rewrite-main-domain-to-sub-folder-without-changing-url) and [Qestion2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303192/how-to-change-below-rewrite-url-to-allow-more-sub-folder-when-all-url-redirecte) but they are not applicable on my example. Consider the following situation

```
www.mywebsite.com/about/overview
```

rewrites to

```
www.mywebsite.com/about/index.php?a=overview
```

Similarly

```
www.mywebsite.com/contact-us/office
```

rewrites to

```
www.mywebsite.com/contact-us/index.php?a=office
```

or

```
www.mywebsite.com/contact-us/home
```

rewrites to

```
www.mywebsite.com/contact-us/index.php?a=home
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/index.php?a=$2 [L,QSA]
```